# Monotone discontinuous function, domain being the set of rationals.

Tags: real-analysis

We can construct a monotone function on the set of reals R having discontinuity only at rationals.But is it possible to construct a monotone function whose domain is the set of rationals Q having discontinuity in whole Q ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a well known example of such a  function is $F(x)=\sum_{x\geq r_n} \frac  1 {2^{n}}$ where $(r_n)$ is an enumeration of the set of all rational numbers.  This function has a jump of  $\frac  1 {2^{n}}$ at $r_n$ for each $n$.